# Eloquent not returning records when using SoftDeletes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having a weird issue, I uploaded my application to my server for live testing.  I am able to save data but nothing is returned when I try to get all rows using Eloquent.  However on my localhost it works just fine.

I have tried:

```
$xtras = Extra::with('category')->paginate(10);
```

and

```
$xtras = Extra::with('category')->get();
```

and

```
$xtras = Extra::all();
```

But none of the above worked, when I returned `$xtras` it was always an empty array.

So then I decided to try:

```
$xtras = DB::table('extras')->get();
```

And that seems to work just fine, it returns the data.  I have checked my model and nothing seems missing because like I said it works on my localhost just not on my server.

This is my Extra class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Extra extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $appends = ['checked'];


    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ExtraCategory');
    }

    public function getCheckedAttribute() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the `Extra` class definition, please.

Comment: Have you checked the log files?

Comment: @bishop I have edited my post.

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanu Yes I have done that and no errors are being thrown, only warning in my error_log file is about "Automatically populating $HTTP_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in the future"

Comment: Alright, class definition looks fine. Since it is a weird issue, let's do the standard thing: restart your web server. Also verify with full namespace `\App\Models\Extra::all()`.

Comment: Just tried both, didn't work, no change, still returns no data.

Comment: Do they show up if you add the `withTrashed()` scope to your query: `Extra::withTrashed()->get()`?

Comment: @patricus that made me check the DB and I noticed the deleted at column had a default date of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' on the server and not on my localhost that is why the records weren't being displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `SoftDeletes`, any value in your `deleted_at` column other than `NULL` will tell Laravel that that record is "deleted", so it won't show up in normal Eloquent queries, unless you use the `withTrashed()` scope.

Take a look at how you're saving/inserting the data and make sure that the `deleted_at` column is being set to `NULL` for records that are not supposed to be deleted.

Comment: this helped me, i've accidentally put a value on the "deleted_at" column accidentally without noticing it.